# Assign value to cell in column depending on name of column - matrix

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix that dynamically displays columns and rows. (dûh)

I will always have a (dynamic) column with the name 'Everyone'.
Now I am looking to color those cells green that have  value > 0 AND columname 'Everyone'

I think I should be doing something with  a IIF statement but how do I find the name of the column for a specific cell?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Henro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a column is in scope of a group (a column/row group) using an InScope expression - you should be able to do this on the background colour expression of the offending cell

How is the column defined? Is it using a grouping or are you adding a static column using the advanced editor? Either way you should be able to use the InScope function to check if the cell belongs to a certain column

e.g.

```
=iif(someColumn.Value > 0 AND InScope("ColumnGroup"), "Green", Nothing)
```

Give a bit more info on the groups/layout and I might be able to help a bit more

Comment: Well, actually you solved my problem. Apologies for reacting so late, it is and has been hectic here. But yes, using the InScope did exactly what I wanted it to do!